# scanf: "%[^,]s" vs "%[^,],s"

Tags: c, scanf

I read it [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tips/tip/the-power-of-scanf), but I'm unable to grasp it.

```
//assume a and b are char arrays

scanf("%[^,]s",a);     // first scanf()

scanf("%[^,],s",b);    // second scanf()
```

I can understand that the first `scanf()` will scan the string until `','` is encountered. But what about the second one?

This [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tips/tip/the-power-of-scanf) says that the first `scanf()` will not trash the comma while the second one will trash it.

What does `trash the comma` mean exactly?

Comment: remove `s` from `"%[^,]s"` and `("%[^,],s"`

Comment: You misquote the original link. There is no `s` in the format strings. "Trash" means "remove from the input stream". The second scanf will remove the `,`, which means that another `getchar()` will read the next character after the comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf("%[^,]s",a);` will read up to `,` and then **leave** `,` in input buffer .
`scanf("%[^,],s",a);` will read up to `,` and after reading `,`, it will **discard** it.

And both of them will read and discard the trailing `s`.

Try this sample code and see the difference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char a[10];
   char b;
   scanf("%[^,]s",a);
   //scanf("%[^,],s",b); 
   scanf("%c", &b);
   printf("%s\n%c", a, b);
}
```

Comment: thanks ,but first one also discards it
I mean if we print it with printf() then output is same

Comment: @A.s.Bhullar No, the first one does not discard it. The difference is what is *left in the input stream*.

Comment: You meant `scanf("%[^,],s",a)` in the second case, right ?

Comment: @Chnossos; Yes. That was a typo. I missed that `,` :)

Comment: @haccks I tried one scanf() after first one scanf("%c",b); ,according to you if it leaves ',' in input buffer then scanf("%c",b); will read this ',' but it is not reading

Comment: @haccks thanks for telling online compile option
I have done it same result is here ,it is not reading ','

Comment: Did you tried this code: `#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char a[10];
   char b;
   scanf("%[^,]s",a);
   scanf("%c", &b);
   printf("%s\n%c", a, b);
}
` ?

Comment: @haccks Yes got it now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56838/discussion-between-a-s-bhullar-and-haccks).

Answer (score 3):

Note that `%[…]` on its own is a complete conversion specification.  See the POSIX specification for [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) for the gory details, or the man page on your system.

Of your two statements:

```
scanf("%[^,]s",a);     // first scanf()
```

This sort of works, but doesn't really do what you (probably) expect it to do.  It reads a sequence of non-comma characters up to the first comma, and then fails to match the `s` but has no way to report that failure.  The next character from the input will be a comma (or EOF if there are no commas in the input).

```
scanf("%[^,],s",b);    // second scanf()
```

This also sort of works, but also doesn't do quite what you expect.  It reads a sequence of non-comma characters, then the comma, and then an `s`, but it also has no way of reporting whether it read either the comma or the `s` after it.  If there is a comma and an `s` after it in the input, then the next input character will be whatever follows the `s`.  If there is a comma and a non-`s`, then the non-`s` will be the next character read.  Otherwise, the next read will return EOF.

Both statements are written badly.  It would be much better if the code tested the return status, and was written as:

```
if (scanf("%[^,],s", b) != 1)
    …report problem…
```

Note that if the next character in the input is a comma, all the statements will return 0, indicating that no information was available to be read into `b`.

Comment: "This sort of works, but doesn't really do what you expect." Don't you mean "but not for the reason you think."? Anyway +1.

Comment: Is there a significant difference between the two options?  I've marginally tweaked the wording (with 'probably'), but I don't see the substantive difference between "works but does not do what you expect" and "works but not for the reason you think".

Comment: Yes, there's a significant difference. You explained exactly why it works as expected, even though the s is not part of the format specifier. The reason is completely different from what is expected thouggh.

Answer (score 0):

They both place the same characters in the target variable (a or b), but the second one ALSO skips over the comma so that the NEXT read will not start with it.